# Recieve Message from Active MQ continously

Tags: java, tomcat, jms, activemq-classic

Below is my code to receive the message from active mq in java

```
public void main(){
                   try{ // Create a ConnectionFactory
  ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("myurl");

  // Create a Connection
  connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
  connection.start();
  // System.out.println(connection.toString());

  //connection.setExceptionListener(this);

  // Create a Session
  session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

  // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
  Destination destination = session.createQueue("myqueuename");
  consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
while (true)//never ending loop
  {
    message = consumer.receive(); //System would wait here to read the message from the queue
    if (message instanceof TextMessage)
    {
      TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
      String text = textMessage.getText();

     System.out.println(text);

      message.acknowledge();
      session.commit(); 
    }

    }
}
finaly{
closeallconnection();
}
```

Since the while condition is true, the loop will continuously run and message.receive will wait until there is a new message. So, the problem here is I am running this from the apache tomcat and it was running successfully, but when I shutdown the tomcat this code is running behind even when I shutdown the tomcat.
If I start the tomcat again there will another service running with same even though existing code is there.
So, the help I need here is how can I receive the message continuously and wait for new messages and when I shutdown the tomcat how to shutdown this jms listener. Since, I dont know how many messages are going to be there in the queue and when I am going to get the message. Any help and suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show is not really production grade code. While doing a receive-loop is not a bad idea, you need some boiler plate logic behind the scene, like put that code in a configurable number of threads, handle exceptions and reconnections, and integrate into your apps life cycle in general.

You typically want some web app framework, such as spring to help out with these tasks.

In recent versions of Spring, you can even do things using annotations which make it pretty simple. With spring boot you need no heavy configuration, but a simple connection string in a property file.

```
@Component
public class MessageListener {

    @JmsListener(destination = "my.queue")
    public void receiveMessage(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Received :" + msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Petter, I am sorry this is not a top level programming, because we are using stupid framework which is developed by an individual so we cannot use spring or struts or hibernate or anything in our application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best way to do it.  It cannot scale.

You don't want one listener/processor; you want a pool of them.  When a message lands on the queue, a listener will be checked out of the pool, processor that message, and go back into the pool when it's done.

That will scale, because a heavy load can be processed by multiple listeners.  One message per request.

Comment: I am sorry @duffymo I am not able to understand your answer, there is only one producer and one consumer, so basically it is one to one but I dont know when the producer is going to send but all I want is receive the message's as soon as the producer sends it.

Comment: You need multiple consumers.  That's what queues do.  They allow asynch processing.  No while loop in a consumer.  That's what I object to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as you @GRK , I didn't want to use an infinite loop to keep the consumer listening. [This](https://riptutorial.com/java-ee/example/27544/using-activemq-library-for-messaging--activemq-jms-provider-specific-implementations-) is the simplest solution that I found that seems to work for me.

```java
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

            consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                public void onMessage(Message msg) {
                    try {
                        if (!(msg instanceof TextMessage))
                            throw new RuntimeException("no text message");
                        TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) msg;
                        System.out.println(tm.getText()); // print message
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        System.err.println("Error reading message");
                    }
                }
            });
```

By using the MessageListener or a class that extends the JMS MessageListener, you are able to handle any messages that come in and still have the code deployed, and not hanging in an infinite loop.